# GeoDjango: Move a coordinate a fixed distance in a given direction (e.g. move a point east by one mile)

Tags: python, django, geodjango

Given a Point (django.contrib.gis.geos.Point) how do I find another point 1 mile east from that Point object?

```
(A) ---[ 1 mile ]---> (B)
```

---

**My failed attempts:**

- I've considered trying to go hardcode the *1 mile east point* but due
  to the curvature of the earth. The miles per degree change.
- Copius googling on SO and Geo Info Exchange. I assume I cannot find the terminology?

---

- Python 3.6
- Django 1.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [Geod class](https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj.Geod-class.html) of pyproj.

```
from pyproj import Geod
geoid = Geod(ellps='WGS84')

def add_distance(lat, lng, az, dist):
    lng_new, lat_new, return_az = geoid.fwd(lon, lat, az, dist)
    return lat_new, lng_new
```

- lng: starting longitude
- lat: starting latitude
- az: azimuth, the direction of movement
- dist: distance in meters

So for your specific question, you could do the following:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

def move_point_mile_east(point):
    dist = 1609.34
    lat, lng = add_distance(point.y, point.x, 90, dist)
    return Point(lng, lat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note there appears to be a typo in the answer by roob above. In the definition of the `add_distance` function the argument `lng` is used, but then in the body of that function the variable `lon` is used. These need to be the same, of course.

Otherwise it's an excellent answer. Thank you.